# Why does packaging indicate that a ribeye cut needs to reach 165 F?

Tags: food-safety, meat, temperature, steak

Even though the FDA recommends 145 F as the safe temperature for whole cuts of beef, this ribeye I bought, as per packaging instructions, needs to reach a *minimum* internal temperature of 165 F.

Could this be an indicator of poor meat handling/quality (cut was priced at $50 per kilo)?

Comment: It may just be that the seller does not want to handle claims and as such advices the extreme high temp.

Comment: It could be that you don't want to eat rib-eye with uncooked fat.

Comment: @Tetsujin but shouldn't a proper sear and basting the steak to even ~130F render it out?

Comment: @Tetsujin I usually cook it to ~130F then rest for ~6 mins, and so far the fat has always been rendered out and cooked

Comment: @Willeke but wouldn't following the FDA guidelines be sufficient?

Comment: @user256872, I do not live in the USA and our advice culture is different here. But I noticed in laundry advice that tumble drying is not allowed while non of those items gets damaged in my tumble dryer (yes, I ignore the advice) and I guess this cooking advice is something like that. Not needed but it keeps the people from complaining if they handle normal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without more information, it's not possible to give a definitive answer. The two main possibilities are:

**The producer is unusually risk-averse.** They are erring on the side of extreme caution in their labelling, because for whatever reason they believe if they label the beef with a lower minimum temperature they will have more trouble in some way unrelated to the actual safety of the beef for consumption.

**There is some reason this beef should be cooked to a higher temperature.** For example, perhaps the beef has been tenderised using needles which could transfer pathogens from the surface to the inside of the meat. The manufacturer knows their product and has deviated from FDA guidance for the reason of food safety or quality.

Answer (score 1):

I've been seeing this temperature on practically every package of food I buy these days, even though the safe cooking temperatures for different meats, and non meat products, vary by up to 30 degrees. 165 is likely to yield a dry, over-cooked steak. Current USDA advice is 145 with a three minute rest time, the previous standard was 160 with no rest time. I'd stick with what culinary experts and the USDA recommend. The URL for this post says 2011, but it was updated in June, 2020.

[Cooking Meat? Check the New Recommended Temperatures](https://www.usda.gov/media/blog/2011/05/25/cooking-meat-check-new-recommended-temperatures)